# XCTU for programming?

Tags: uart, xbee, zigbee

I am new to Xbee and XCTU software and I wanted know if it is possible to use XCTU to send a "programmed sequence". By that I mean, send something, wait 10 seconds, if receive this thing send this etc. I know that XCTU is not an IDE and that it is not really intended for this but I would like to be able to do this kind of things. If anyone has an idea I would be really happy :)

Answer (score 3):

XCTU can't really do dynamic things like that.  It's built almost exclusively to update firmware / check radio settings (and it's not even that good at that).  You can send the same packet over and over every 10 seconds (Use the green + to make one, then send the sequence)

[image]

However, as it turns out, your "programmed sequence" requires a program.  A quick search yielded: https://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/

Python's pretty easy to get started with.  There's equivalents for other languages, but you can't get away from the fact that you'll have to program.  Open up a serial port (with the COM4/5/6 that you see in xctu) and then send and receive messages using the library.